# Regex conditional replacement

Tags: regex, if-statement

I wonder if it is possible to make a condition in a regex replacement?

Let's take a simple example:

- every `<filename>.orig` should be changed for `<filename>.dest`
- every `_<filename>.orig` should be changed for `default.dest`

Using this regex, I capture `<filename>` in group 2 if it's prefixed by an underscore, else in group 3:

```
/^(_)?((?(1)[a-z-]+|))((?(1)|[a-z-]+))?\.orig$/i
```

Now, I would like to use a conditional statement (`/(?(if)then|else)/`) in the replacement which would looks like this:

```
/^(_)?((?(1)[a-z-]+|))((?(1)|[a-z-]+))?\.orig$/(?($2)default|$3)\.dest/i
```

Obviously, and unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+    +----+-----+-----+
| Input       | Output                | Expected     |    | $1 | $2  | $3  |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+    +----+-----+-----+
| foo.origin  | (?()default|foo).dest | foo.dest     |    |    |     | foo |
| bar.origin  | (?()default|bar).dest | bar.dest     |    |    |     | bar |
| _baz.origin | (?(baz)default|).dest | default.dest |    | _  | baz |     |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------------+    +----+-----+-----+
```

Does anyone knows a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: it's based on the language you're running. I think  it would be possible in Perl .

Comment: What language are you doing this in? That would help break it down .. Also just an FYI the conditional is not necessary to do this, in fact it seems to be too much.

Comment: I agree with @AvinashRaj. As far as I know, it wouldn't be possible in Python. You would have to call each regex's replace method individually.

Comment: I'm writing Sublime Text snippets, so I assume Python is behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in most languages is:

```
^(?:([^_]\S*)|_\S+)\.orig$
```

And inspect the capture group, if it's empty, replace with `default.dest`, otherwise replace with `\1.dest`. The inspecting a capture-group part happens in a language, but you can see something similar already **[here](http://regex101.com/r/mN9vL2/1)**.

Comment: Sure I could inspect the capture-group. That's easy, and I would have obviously chosen this way if it was possible. Unfortunately, in this specific context (ST3 Builds) I only can use a single regex to get my result, nothing more.

Comment: Afaik there is no such thing as conditional replacement, like there is conditional matching. This is because regexes are a matching tool primarily. Notice _tool_ there, pardon my opinion here but I strongly feel that people need to understand regular expressions are a _tool_, not a _solution_. Frameworks that allow you to only specify 1 (or 2) regex(es) to do all the work for a specific task evidently do not understand this important difference. You were not involved in that Sublime Text design choice I take it ;) Just spreading the gospel here.